# Laravel 8: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'answer' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project which is an Online Forum. And in this forum, basically users can answer to questions.

So at the Controller, I put this for posting answers:

```
public function PostAnswer($id)
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
            'answer' => 'required',
        ])->validated();

        $answer = Answer::create([
            'answer' => $validate_data['answer'],
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'question_id' => $id,
        ]);

        return back();
    }
```

Note that `$id` variable is the question id.

But now the problem is whenever I try to add an answer, I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
> **1364 Field 'answer' doesn't have a default value**

The form behind this goes here:

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.answers', $show->id) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea
   @error('answer')
     <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
        {{ $message }}
     </div>
   @enderror
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And here is also the Migration of `answers` table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('answer');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('question_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

If you want to look at relations between Models, here it is:

**Question.php:**

```
public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
```

**User.php:**

```
public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
    }
```

So what is going wrong here, how can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share your idea or suggestion on this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Answer Model, make sure you have `$fillable` property with correct properties:

```
class Answer extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['answer','user_id','question_id'];
....
}
```